# jquery ui datepicker - firstday

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

in my code i used first day to set the day names starting from monday ... sunday.
the code snippet is

```
$( ".txt_calender" ).datepicker({
            minDate: 0,
            firstDay: 1,
            dateFormat: '<?php if (isset(Yii::app()->session['jsDateFormat']))
{
    echo Yii::app()->session['jsDateFormat'];
} else
{
    echo 'm/d/Y';
} ?>'
        });
```

but when i click the textbox, it shows day names starts from sunday. what is the issue with the code snippet.

Comment: Can you paste us from source view the value returned from the session?
Any difference with 'm/d/Y' ? seems to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/tive/Stc5W/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting it after init like

```
$( ".txt_calender" ).datepicker({
            minDate: 0,
            dateFormat: '<?php if (isset(Yii::app()->session['jsDateFormat']))
{
    echo Yii::app()->session['jsDateFormat'];
} else
{
    echo 'm/d/Y';
} ?>'
        });


    $( ".txt_calender" ).datepicker( "option", "firstDay", 1 );
```

Comment: cool was a stab in the dark answer glad its working and good luck with your project